# Handling Associative array response from REST in Android

Tags: android, rest, associative-array, xml-rpc, retrofit2

I am calling a get request from Android and url looks like this:

http://____.com/API/fetchtopic.php?topicId=2&api_key=8c5d8571f7c1c4b4189d0ef623bcdu76

The response is coming as associative array like below.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 27 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
  <title/>
</head>
<body>Array ( [methodResponse] => Array ( [params] => Array ( [param] => Array ( [value] => Array ( [struct] => Array ( [member] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => member_id [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => name [value] => Array ( [string] => Admin ) ) [2] => Array ( [name] => member_group_id [value] => Array ( [string] => 4 ) ) [3] => Array ( [name] => email [value] => Array ( [string] => admin@___.com ) ) [4] => Array ( [name] => joined [value] => Array ( [string] => 1453296128 ) ) [5] => Array ( [name] => ip_address [value] => Array ( [string] => 1__.__.__.104 ) ) [6] => Array ( [name] => posts [value] => Array ( [string] => 10 ) ) [7] => Array ( [name] => title [value] => Array ( [string] => Administrator ) ) [8] => Array ( [name] => allow_admin_mails [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [9] => Array ( [name] => time_offset [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [10] => Array ( [name] => skin [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [11] => Array ( [name] => warn_level [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [12] => Array ( [name] => warn_lastwarn [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [13] => Array ( [name] => language [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [14] => Array ( [name] => last_post [value] => Array ( [string] => 1454250091 ) ) [15] => Array ( [name] => restrict_post [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [16] => Array ( [name] => view_sigs [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [17] => Array ( [name] => view_img [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [18] => Array ( [name] => bday_day [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [19] => Array ( [name] => bday_month [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [20] => Array ( [name] => bday_year [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [21] => Array ( [name] => msg_count_new [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [22] => Array ( [name] => msg_count_total [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [23] => Array ( [name] => msg_count_reset [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [24] => Array ( [name] => msg_show_notification [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [25] => Array ( [name] => misc [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [26] => Array ( [name] => last_visit [value] => Array ( [string] => 1455068941 ) ) [27] => Array ( [name] => last_activity [value] => Array ( [string] => 1455382519 ) ) [28] => Array ( [name] => dst_in_use [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [29] => Array ( [name] => coppa_user [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [30] => Array ( [name] => mod_posts [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [31] => Array ( [name] => auto_track [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [32] => Array ( [name] => temp_ban [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [33] => Array ( [name] => login_anonymous [value] => Array ( [base64] => MCYx ) ) [34] => Array ( [name] => ignored_users [value] => Array ( [string] => a:0:{} ) ) [35] => Array ( [name] => mgroup_others [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [36] => Array ( [name] => org_perm_id [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [37] => Array ( [name] => member_login_key [value] => Array ( [string] => f6742075c41b313 ) ) [38] => Array ( [name] => member_login_key_expire [value] => Array ( [string] => 1455987319 ) ) [39] => Array ( [name] => has_blog [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [40] => Array ( [name] => blogs_recache [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [41] => Array ( [name] => has_gallery [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [42] => Array ( [name] => members_auto_dst [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [43] => Array ( [name] => members_display_name [value] => Array ( [string] => Admin ) ) [44] => Array ( [name] => members_seo_name [value] => Array ( [string] => admin ) ) [45] => Array ( [name] => members_created_remote [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [46] => Array ( [name] => members_cache [value] => Array ( [string] => a:4:{s:11:"report_temp";a:0:{}s:19:"report_last_updated";i:1453296329;s:10:"report_num";s:1:"0";s:13:"msgAlertReset";i:1453557778;} ) ) [47] => Array ( [name] => members_disable_pm [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [48] => Array ( [name] => members_l_display_name [value] => Array ( [string] => admin ) ) [49] => Array ( [name] => members_l_username [value] => Array ( [string] => admin ) ) [50] => Array ( [name] => failed_logins [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [51] => Array ( [name] => failed_login_count [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [52] => Array ( [name] => members_profile_views [value] => Array ( [string] => 6 ) ) [53] => Array ( [name] => members_pass_hash [value] => Array ( [string] => fb6abd62883ffb ) ) [54] => Array ( [name] => members_pass_salt [value] => Array ( [string] => ^sG]X ) ) [55] => Array ( [name] => member_banned [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [56] => Array ( [name] => member_uploader [value] => Array ( [string] => flash ) ) [57] => Array ( [name] => members_bitoptions [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [58] => Array ( [name] => fb_uid [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [59] => Array ( [name] => fb_emailhash [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [60] => Array ( [name] => fb_lastsync [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [61] => Array ( [name] => members_day_posts [value] => Array ( [string] => 0,0 ) ) [62] => Array ( [name] => live_id [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [63] => Array ( [name] => twitter_id [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [64] => Array ( [name] => twitter_token [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [65] => Array ( [name] => twitter_secret [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [66] => Array ( [name] => notification_cnt [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [67] => Array ( [name] => tc_lastsync [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [68] => Array ( [name] => fb_session [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [69] => Array ( [name] => fb_token [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [70] => Array ( [name] => ips_mobile_token [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [71] => Array ( [name] => unacknowledged_warnings [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [72] => Array ( [name] => ipsconnect_id [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [73] => Array ( [name] => ipsconnect_revalidate_url [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [74] => Array ( [name] => chat_banned [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [75] => Array ( [name] => my_member_id [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [76] => Array ( [name] => field_1 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [77] => Array ( [name] => field_2 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [78] => Array ( [name] => field_3 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [79] => Array ( [name] => field_4 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [80] => Array ( [name] => field_5 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [81] => Array ( [name] => field_6 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [82] => Array ( [name] => field_7 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [83] => Array ( [name] => field_8 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [84] => Array ( [name] => field_9 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [85] => Array ( [name] => field_10 [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [86] => Array ( [name] => eco_points [value] => Array ( [string] => 51.00 ) ) [87] => Array ( [name] => eco_worth [value] => Array ( [string] => 51.00 ) ) [88] => Array ( [name] => eco_welfare [value] => Array ( [string] => 0.00 ) ) [89] => Array ( [name] => eco_on_welfare [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [90] => Array ( [name] => pp_member_id [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [91] => Array ( [name] => pp_last_visitors [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [92] => Array ( [name] => pp_rating_hits [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [93] => Array ( [name] => pp_rating_value [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [94] => Array ( [name] => pp_rating_real [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [95] => Array ( [name] => pp_main_photo [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [96] => Array ( [name] => pp_main_width [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [97] => Array ( [name] => pp_main_height [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [98] => Array ( [name] => pp_thumb_photo [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [99] => Array ( [name] => pp_thumb_width [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [100] => Array ( [name] => pp_thumb_height [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [101] => Array ( [name] => pp_setting_moderate_comments [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [102] => Array ( [name] => pp_setting_moderate_friends [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [103] => Array ( [name] => pp_setting_count_friends [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [104] => Array ( [name] => pp_setting_count_comments [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [105] => Array ( [name] => pp_setting_count_visitors [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [106] => Array ( [name] => pp_about_me [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [107] => Array ( [name] => pp_reputation_points [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [108] => Array ( [name] => pp_gravatar [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [109] => Array ( [name] => pp_photo_type [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [110] => Array ( [name] => signature [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [111] => Array ( [name] => avatar_location [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [112] => Array ( [name] => avatar_size [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [113] => Array ( [name] => avatar_type [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [114] => Array ( [name] => pconversation_filters [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [115] => Array ( [name] => fb_photo [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [116] => Array ( [name] => fb_photo_thumb [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [117] => Array ( [name] => fb_bwoptions [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [118] => Array ( [name] => tc_last_sid_import [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [119] => Array ( [name] => tc_photo [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [120] => Array ( [name] => tc_bwoptions [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [121] => Array ( [name] => pp_customization [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [122] => Array ( [name] => pp_profile_update [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [123] => Array ( [name] => g_id [value] => Array ( [string] => 4 ) ) [124] => Array ( [name] => g_view_board [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [125] => Array ( [name] => g_mem_info [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [126] => Array ( [name] => g_other_topics [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [127] => Array ( [name] => g_use_search [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [128] => Array ( [name] => g_edit_profile [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [129] => Array ( [name] => g_post_new_topics [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [130] => Array ( [name] => g_reply_own_topics [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [131] => Array ( [name] => g_reply_other_topics [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [132] => Array ( [name] => g_edit_posts [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [133] => Array ( [name] => g_delete_own_posts [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [134] => Array ( [name] => g_open_close_posts [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [135] => Array ( [name] => g_delete_own_topics [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [136] => Array ( [name] => g_post_polls [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [137] => Array ( [name] => g_vote_polls [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [138] => Array ( [name] => g_use_pm [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [139] => Array ( [name] => g_is_supmod [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [140] => Array ( [name] => g_access_cp [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [141] => Array ( [name] => g_title [value] => Array ( [string] => Administrators ) ) [142] => Array ( [name] => g_append_edit [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [143] => Array ( [name] => g_access_offline [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [144] => Array ( [name] => g_avoid_q [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [145] => Array ( [name] => g_avoid_flood [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [146] => Array ( [name] => g_icon [value] => Array ( [string] => public/style_extra/team_icons/admin.png ) ) [147] => Array ( [name] => g_attach_max [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [148] => Array ( [name] => prefix [value] => Array ( [base64] => PHNwYW4gc3R5bGU9J2NvbG9yOnJlZDsnPg== ) ) [149] => Array ( [name] => suffix [value] => Array ( [base64] => PC9zcGFuPg== ) ) [150] => Array ( [name] => g_max_messages [value] => Array ( [string] => 50 ) ) [151] => Array ( [name] => g_max_mass_pm [value] => Array ( [string] => 6 ) ) [152] => Array ( [name] => g_search_flood [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [153] => Array ( [name] => g_edit_cutoff [value] => Array ( [string] => 5 ) ) [154] => Array ( [name] => g_promotion [value] => Array ( [base64] => LTEmLTE= ) ) [155] => Array ( [name] => g_hide_from_list [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [156] => Array ( [name] => g_post_closed [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [157] => Array ( [name] => g_perm_id [value] => Array ( [string] => 4 ) ) [158] => Array ( [name] => g_photo_max_vars [value] => Array ( [string] => 500:170:240 ) ) [159] => Array ( [name] => g_dohtml [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [160] => Array ( [name] => g_edit_topic [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [161] => Array ( [name] => g_bypass_badwords [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [162] => Array ( [name] => g_can_msg_attach [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [163] => Array ( [name] => g_attach_per_post [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [164] => Array ( [name] => g_topic_rate_setting [value] => Array ( [string] => 2 ) ) [165] => Array ( [name] => g_dname_changes [value] => Array ( [string] => 3 ) ) [166] => Array ( [name] => g_dname_date [value] => Array ( [string] => 30 ) ) [167] => Array ( [name] => g_mod_preview [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [168] => Array ( [name] => g_rep_max_positive [value] => Array ( [string] => 100 ) ) [169] => Array ( [name] => g_rep_max_negative [value] => Array ( [string] => 100 ) ) [170] => Array ( [name] => g_signature_limits [value] => Array ( [string] => 0::::: ) ) [171] => Array ( [name] => g_can_add_friends [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [172] => Array ( [name] => g_hide_online_list [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [173] => Array ( [name] => g_bitoptions [value] => Array ( [string] => 27262912 ) ) [174] => Array ( [name] => g_pm_perday [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [175] => Array ( [name] => g_mod_post_unit [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [176] => Array ( [name] => g_ppd_limit [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [177] => Array ( [name] => g_ppd_unit [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [178] => Array ( [name] => g_displayname_unit [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [179] => Array ( [name] => g_sig_unit [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [180] => Array ( [name] => g_pm_flood_mins [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [181] => Array ( [name] => g_max_notifications [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [182] => Array ( [name] => g_max_bgimg_upload [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [183] => Array ( [name] => g_eco [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [184] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_bank [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [185] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_welfare [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [186] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_loan [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [187] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_stock [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [188] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_cc [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [189] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_lt [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [190] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_shopitem [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [191] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_asset [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [192] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_transaction [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [193] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_lt_max [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [194] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_bank_max [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [195] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_cash_adv_max [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [196] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_stock_max [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [197] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_welfare_max [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [198] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_bal_trnsfr_max [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [199] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_max_pts [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [200] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_max_cc_debt [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [201] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_max_loan_debt [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [202] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_frm_ptsx [value] => Array ( [string] => 0.00 ) ) [203] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_edit_pts [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [204] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_lottery [value] => Array ( [string] => 1 ) ) [205] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_lottery_tix [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [206] => Array ( [name] => g_eco_lottery_odds [value] => Array ( [string] => 0 ) ) [207] => Array ( [name] => cache_content [value] => Array ( [string] => ) ) [208] => Array ( [name] => full [value] => Array ( [boolean] => 1 ) ) [209] => Array ( [name] => photoMaxKb [value] => Array ( [int] => 500 ) ) [210] => Array ( [name] => photoMaxWidth [value] => Array ( [int] => 170 ) ) [211] => Array ( [name] => photoMaxHeight [value] => Array ( [int] => 240 ) ) [212] => Array ( [name] => gbw_mod_post_unit_type [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [213] => Array ( [name] => gbw_ppd_unit_type [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [214] => Array ( [name] => gbw_displayname_unit_type [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [215] => Array ( [name] => gbw_sig_unit_type [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [216] => Array ( [name] => gbw_promote_unit_type [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [217] => Array ( [name] => gbw_no_status_update [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [218] => Array ( [name] => gbw_soft_delete [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [219] => Array ( [name] => gbw_soft_delete_own [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [220] => Array ( [name] => gbw_soft_delete_own_topic [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [221] => Array ( [name] => gbw_un_soft_delete [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [222] => Array ( [name] => gbw_soft_delete_see [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [223] => Array ( [name] => gbw_soft_delete_topic [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [224] => Array ( [name] => gbw_un_soft_delete_topic [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [225] => Array ( [name] => gbw_soft_delete_topic_see [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [226] => Array ( [name] => gbw_soft_delete_reason [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [227] => Array ( [name] => gbw_soft_delete_see_post [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [228] => Array ( [name] => gbw_allow_customization [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [229] => Array ( [name] => gbw_allow_url_bgimage [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [230] => Array ( [name] => gbw_allow_upload_bgimage [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [231] => Array ( [name] => gbw_view_reps [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [232] => Array ( [name] => gbw_no_status_import [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [233] => Array ( [name] => gbw_disable_tagging [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [234] => Array ( [name] => gbw_disable_prefixes [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [235] => Array ( [name] => gbw_view_last_info [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [236] => Array ( [name] => gbw_view_online_lists [value] => Array ( [int] => 1 ) ) [237] => Array ( [name] => gbw_hide_leaders_page [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [238] => Array ( [name] => _canBeIgnored [value] => Array ( [boolean] => ) ) [239] => Array ( [name] => bw_is_spammer [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [240] => Array ( [name] => bw_from_sfs [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [241] => Array ( [name] => bw_vnc_type [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [242] => Array ( [name] => bw_forum_result_type [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [243] => Array ( [name] => bw_no_status_update [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [244] => Array ( [name] => bw_status_email_mine [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [245] => Array ( [name] => bw_status_email_all [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [246] => Array ( [name] => bw_disable_customization [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [247] => Array ( [name] => bw_local_password_set [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [248] => Array ( [name] => bw_disable_tagging [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [249] => Array ( [name] => bw_disable_prefixes [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [250] => Array ( [name] => bw_using_skin_gen [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [251] => Array ( [name] => bw_disable_gravatar [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [252] => Array ( [name] => bw_paste_plain [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) [253] => Array ( [name] => bw_html_sig [value] => Array ( [int] => 0 ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )</body>
</html>
```

First I tried the Retrofit API using Simple xml converter which shows convertion error.But when then tried with Scalar converter as below:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

Interface:

```
@GET("/API/fetchmemberdetails.php?userId=1&api_key=8c5d8571f7")
Call<String> getLatestPrograms();
```

Am getting the body part.But its going to a single string.

Now am trying the XML-RPC client library (https://github.com/timroes/aXMLRPC).
But not sure how to call this get request by passing these url parameters.

Please help how to map these values from associative array to a java class.

Comment: Looks like you need an HTML parser to get your associative array first

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to get the associative array but the whole content within the <body> tag is going to a single string. I needed it like a key-value pair

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you need to get the content of the body tag, but then parse out whatever format that is... Do you by chance have access to this php file that you're calling? Also, using an XML RPC library won't do anything either because it isn't XML

Comment: Ok . Now I got the content of body tag.But the problem is how could I parse out the values. Like converting json to pojo is there a way to convert associative array.

Comment: I don't recognize that format. It is definitely an associative array, but a neither a JSON or XML parser can read that.

Comment: Like I asked before, it this **your** PHP file that you can modify to actually return JSON data?

Comment: Yes yes thanks.  :-)   .  Converted associative array to JSON using json_encode() method from php file.